# Which is option is best performance?

Tags: sql, performance, db2, sql-update, sql-insert

I'm developping a new feature for my application and i need to add some new data to my database **DB2**.

I already have **1 table with about 50 columns**, where i'm going to get my data to present in my screen. I need 20 more columns to implement my new feature. ***I will always get 1 row at time and only update/insert 1 row each time***.

Which one is best performant? Create 30 columns in the table i already have or create a new 30 column "subtable". And if the option is number 2 what's the best performant way to update my data? **Multiple updates or updates with joins(if it's possible)?**

EDIT:
Correction: My original table has 54 columns

Frequency of inserts/updates of the original 30 columns and the 20 columns.
I don't know what you mean by frequence but it will be updated every 10 or 20 seconds on average.
*(edit: if i'm on an old feature i will **always** update all 30 original columns. If i'm on a new feature i will need to update all 50 columns (30 old + 20 new columns)*

Whether all 50 columns are changed at once.
Yes all columns are changed at once

Query load on the system.
Idk what you mean

Presence of indexes (which slow down updates).
There are 4 indexes in the original table

Whether all the original rows would have the additional 20 columns.
Not all rows we'll need aditional columns

Typical row length:
Chars of 3 and Decimal of 3

Comment: What Db2? What types? Typical row length? Table size? Data page size? How many parallel users? How likely that later new "features" will be added, requiring new columns...?

Comment: max row length 150 (based on typical column length: chars of 3 and decimal of 3). There is no need for separate table.  Using multiple tables complicates programming. Performance wise, single table is better than multiple tables based on max row length.

Answer (score 0):

The performance difference is probably not going to matter much.  Much more information is needed about your environment:

- Frequency of inserts/updates of the original 30 columns and the 20 columns.
- Whether all 50 columns are changed at once.
- Query load on the system.
- Presence of indexes (which slow down updates).
- Whether all the original rows would have the additional 20 columns.

Because this is a new feature, I might be inclined to do the following:

1. Add a new table with the 20 additional rows and a primary key to the original data.
2. Be sure that inserts go into the existing table first, then the new table.
3. If desired, add a view that combines the two tables with a `left join`.

This approach specifically has no impact on the existing table.

If this works and meets your performance goals, fine.  If you find the multiple tables cumbersome, then at a later point, consider modifying your existing table.

Comment: Gordon tks for the answer. I edited my question so it can answer your questions

Comment: @JoãoBaptista "Frequency of inserts/updates of the original 30 columns and the 20 columns. " ... Gordon mean, if you need to update the 20 colums `every time` you update the 30col table, or you update the 20col table less frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Make shure your "old" feature tolerates additional fields present on the table (e.g. it should not contain "select * from ...").

Define the new fields as either nullable or "not null with default" on the existing table.

This should be more performant than having two tables with a left join for the new feature and only has a minimal hit on the old feature performance.

This is also a scalable approach, i.e. if you add a new feature with a few new fields every month then you dont want to end up left joining 12 tables a year from now.

I would go with two tables when

- it is a very rarely used new feature
- the relationship old/new becomes 1:n
- the column-limit on the old table is reached
- old-feature code cannot be tested/changed